# discord.py bot not responding

Tags: python, discord.py, discord-bot

I'm trying to build my first bot, so I'm following the discord.py official examples. I literally copy paste the "basic_voice.py" and didn't touch anything except for token where I replaced it with the my bot's token, this is the code (removed all comands except for join to let the code being more readable here).

```
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = "..."

class Music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def join(self, ctx, *, channel: discord.VoiceChannel):
        """Joins a voice channel"""
        if ctx.voice_client is not None:
            return await ctx.voice_client.move_to(channel)

        await channel.connect()

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix="+",
    description='Relatively simple music bot example',
    intents=intents,
)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user} (ID: {bot.user.id})')
    print('------')


async def main():
    async with bot:
        await bot.add_cog(Music(bot))
        await bot.start(TOKEN)


asyncio.run(main())
```

I run the main and the ready function works well but then in the server even if I try only to use join (+join) it doesn't respond, it doesn't even enter in the command code block (checked with a print).
Tried also basic.py with the super basic add command and even there nothing.
What I'm missing? bot has administrator permissions and I literally copy paste the code from the official repo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you installed discord.py[voice]?

try run this command:

```
pip install discord.py[voice]
```